# Best practices for python abstract class

Tags: python

I came across this code in a codebase:

```
class Worker(object):
    state_names = {}
    def __init__(self, status_value):
        self.status_value = status_value
    @property
    def state(self):
        return self.status_value.value
    @state.setter
    def state(self, status):
        self.ui.debug('state: {} -> {}'
                      ''.format(self.state_name(), self.state_name(status)))
        self.status_value.value = status
    def state_name(self, s=None):
        return self.state_names[s or self.state]
```

There are some obvious problems with it:

1. `self.state_names` is read-only and empty
2. `self.ui` does not exist

And after looking around for awhile, I realized that there was a single class that derived from this and was known to have `self.ui` and provided `self.state_names`.

I think it is kind of odd to implement an abstract class in this way, where the virtual member functions have implementations that assume data members in the derived class.

Is there a better, cleaner way to do this development pattern in python? I am going to assume that AbstractBaseClass is a starting point.